# Efficiently go through values from a vector

Tags: c++, search, vector, grid, find

I have a vector of pairs, which really just store whether cells in a 2D grid are active.

```
vector<pair <int,int>> cellsActive;
```

Now I'm trying to print an arbitrary part of the whole 2D grid, in which all non-active cells are represented with a `.` and the active cells are represented by a `#`.

I implemented this is as following:

1. Create an array `myGrid` as big as the 2D grid and set every character to `.`
2. Iterate through the `cellsActive` vector and get each active cell: `activeCell`
3. Change the grid so that every `activeCell` location (`pair <int int>`) is now represented by a `#`; `myGrid[activeCell.first][activeCell.second] = "#"`
4. Now that `myGrid` correctly holds the values of all cells; loop through the arbitrary part of the `myGrid` and print it.

However, I feel like I should be able to do this more efficiently by just printing the arbitrary part that I want to print as `.` except for the relevant `activeCell` locations that needs to be printed in the form of a `#`. If I find a way to do it like that, I do not have to construct the whole 2D grid and then loop through it again to print it. But on the other hand, I do not know how to efficiently go through the `cellsActive` list and find the relevant cells that I need to represent by a `#`.

I.e. I could do this:

```
for (int y=0; y<arbitrary_y;y++) {
    for (int x=0; x<arbitrary_x;x++) {
        pair <int int> j = make_pair(y, x);
        vector<intpair>::iterator it = find(cellsActive.begin(), cellsActive.end(), j);
        if (it != cellsActive.end()) {
            cout << "#";
        }
        else {
            cout << ".";
        }
    }
}
```

but then I have to search through the whole `cellsActive` vector every time, which seems to be computationally inefficient if the `cellsActive` and `arbitrary_x` and `arbitrary_y` are large.

My question is, what is the computationally the most efficient way to print these `.` and `#` in C++?

Comment: FYI: [Sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix). Though, I'm not quite sure about the "most efficient" way in your case - sparse matrix is the general term worth to research for.

Comment: Iterate over `cellsActive` and test `if (it->first < arbitrary_y && it->second < arbitrary_x)` to get the `#`s?

Comment: Given no further conditions. Your first method is quite efficient in terms of clock cycles. But if `cellsActive` are presorted in the y then x axis. You could do a O(n) iteration through the vector to determine if the current cell is on by having a pointer/index that only increments if the cell it points to is the current cell.

Comment: Can you sort `CellsActive`?

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, I could, but then I have to sort the vector first. I thought about that, but I wonder whether it actually reduces complexion or not. I guess it all depends really. Because the sorting algorithm also depends on how the vector is indexed before sorting etc. Maybe I should do benchmarking.

Comment: @MaryChang Thank you, unfortunately it's not sorted. At least it's good to hear that the first method is quite efficient.

Comment: @Scheff I see, that's interesting, because I can assume sparsity I think.

Comment: @mch True, then I can get the relevant `#`s. (Intuitively) that feels quite efficient, but how would you go about printing it later on? Also thanks for the answers everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 interesting ways:

- create buffer result, and fill it:

  ```
  std::vector<std::vector<char>> chars(arbitrary_x, std::vector<char>(arbitrary_y, '.'));
  // or even better std::vector<char> chars(arbitrary_x * arbitrary_y, '.');

  for (auto [x, y] : cellsActive) {
      if (x < arbitrary_x && y < arbitrary_y) { chars[x][y] = '#'; }
  }

  // display chars.
  ```

  - Complexity: `max(O(N), O(arbitrary_x * arbitrary_y))`
  - Extra memory: `arbitrary_x * arbitrary_y`
- Or sort `cellsActive` and do a merge-like code.

  ```
  auto comp = [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs){
      return std::tie(lhs.second, lhs.first) < std::tie(rhs.second, rhs.first);
  };
  std::sort(cellsActive.begin(), cellsActive.end(), comp);
  auto it = cellsActive.begin();

  for (int y = 0; y < arbitrary_y; y++) {
      for (int x = 0; x < arbitrary_x; x++) {
          const std::pair p{x, y};

          while (it != cellsActive.end() && comp(*it, p)) {
              ++it;
          }
          if (it != cellsActive.end() && *it == p) {
              std::cout << '#';
          } else {
              std::cout << '.';
          }
      }
  }
  // You can even break the loops when `it` reaches the end and print remaining '.'.
  ```

  - Complexity: `max(O(N log N), O(arbitrary_x * arbitrary_y))`
  - No extra memory.